# Flutter: Fetch document count from Firestore Database sub-collection inside a sub-collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have `userCollection` inside that I have `studentCollection` and inside `studentCollection` I have 3 collections namely `revisionCollection`, `currentCollection`,`newCollection`.
I can fetch the length of documents from `studentCollection` means how many students have been added. But my problem is that I am unable to fetch the length of documents inside the next 3 collections inside the `studentCollection`.
Firstly, is it possible?
Secondly, should I be fetching it at the cost of performance and charges?
Third, How should I do it?

**Firestore Function to fetch documents.**

```
// fetching length of individual collections
  Future<int> fetchLengthOfStudentRecords() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = (await firestore
        .collection(FC.pathUserCollection)
        .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection(FC.pathStudentCollection)
        .get());
    return querySnapshot.size;
  }

  Future<int> fetchLengthOfAllRecords(String path) async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore
        .collection(FC.pathUserCollection)
        .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection(FC.pathStudentCollection)
        .doc()
        .collection(path)
        .get();
    return querySnapshot.size;
  }
```

**BlocCubit Logic**.

```
Future<void> fetchRecordsLength() async {
    emit(FetchRecordsLengthState.loading());
    try {
      int studentLength =
          await firestoreRepository.fetchLengthOfStudentRecords();
      int murajaatLength = await firestoreRepository
          .fetchLengthOfAllRecords(FC.pathMurajaatRDCollection);
      int juzHaliLength = await firestoreRepository
          .fetchLengthOfAllRecords(FC.pathJuzHaaliRDCollection);
      int jadeedLength = await firestoreRepository
          .fetchLengthOfAllRecords(FC.pathJadeedRDCollection);
      emit(FetchRecordsLengthState.success(
          student: studentLength,
          murajaat: murajaatLength,
          juzHaali: juzHaliLength,
          jadeed: jadeedLength));
      print('student length: $studentLength');
      print('murajaat length: $murajaatLength');
      print('juzHaali length: $juzHaliLength');
      print('jadeed length: $jadeedLength');
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('fetch records length failure $e');
      }
      emit(FetchRecordsLengthState.failure());
    }
  }
```

Please help me understand this and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, is it possible?

Yes, that's for sure possible. You should create a reference that points to those three sub-collections in particular and then count the documents.

> Secondly, should I be fetching it at the cost of performance and charges?

When you call `.get()` and then you return the size of the `querySnapshot`, it means that you read all the documents in the snapshot object. This also means that you'll have to pay a read operation for each document that exists inside the collection. Nowadays, there is another solution that can help you count the documents in a collection which is by using [Aggregation Queries](https://Aggregation%20Queries). So you should call [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) and you'll be charged with one document read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query. So it's much cheaper than your actual solution.

**Edit:**

> Is it possible for you to give an example about referencing the sub-collections?

Considering you have a structure that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- userCollection (collection)
      |
      --- $userId (document)
           |
           --- studentCollection (sub-collection)
                 |
                 --- $studentId (document)
                       |
                       |
                       --- revisionCollection (sub-collection)
                       |
                       --- currentCollection (sub-collection)
                       |
                       --- newCollection (sub-collection)
```

To create a reference that points to the `revisionCollection` sub-collection, something like below is needed:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = (await firestore
    .collection(FC.pathUserCollection)
    .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection(FC.pathStudentCollection)
    .doc("student ID")
    .collection(FC.pathRevisionCollection)
    .get());
```

Please also note that when you are calling `doc()` as in the following lines of code:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore
    .collection(FC.pathUserCollection)
    .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection(FC.pathStudentCollection)
    .doc() //
    .collection(path)
    .get();
```

Without passing any parameter to the `doc()` function, it means that you create a unique reference to a document within your `FC.pathStudentCollection` collection, which doesn't help. You have to pass as an argument of the existing student ID, not something new.

Comment: Thank you replying back swiftly. Is it possible for you to can give an example about referencing to the sub-collections? Secondly, I am aware of the count() aggregator and I will be using it. Actually I cam across it after I posted this question.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Okay so I understand the issue. I have to pass a parameter inside doc() as in id. But here the problem is that the Id is dynamically generated by the system. I have to retrieve then studentId and then pass it to doc(). I tried getting studentId through DocumentReference. Is that correct?

Comment: You need to know the student ID ahead of time to be able to create that reference. So you have to store it somewhere so it can be used to create that reference.

Comment: So I tried passing a specific studentId, then I was able to fetch the length of records. But my requirement is not specific to a single studentId, I want to display the count of all documents saved in those collections and it should get updated everytime a new record is added in those collection.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to fetch the length of records when passing a student ID. If you need to count all documents saved in those collections, then you should consider using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and attach a [persistent listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). Unfortunately, `count()` doesn't provide realtime updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for the all help you provided.

Comment: You're very welcome, Sulli.